# How can I handle large post data in google-app-engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm working on a web based data visualization application. In some cases the uploaded data files have a size of several tens of MB. Connection drops should not be an issue since the users are typically from a university environment with good connections.
I basically want to only process the data directly rather then saving it, because 99% is discarded anyways.
What is a simple way to handle this GET requests, since they are over the limit of standard GAE GET sizes.

Comment: For uploading big files you have the blobstore. There is no size limit. The limit of 50 MB has been dropped. You have to wait for a finished upload to process the blob.

Comment: However this the following still true?
"In addition to systemwide safety quotas, a limit applies specifically to the use of the Blobstore: the maximum size of Blobstore data that can be read by the application with one API call is 32 megabytes."

Comment: I never used it, but you can seek and read. This makes it possible to read a big file in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

If You are uploading a file which is taking more time. you can use taskqueues for uploading that data. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/.Dont process the data when user uploaded. Just store that data in temparory storage table. In task queue process the data.